# weird result in realtime in analytics, no idea what to do

Tags: google-analytics

I am getting a weird result in the realtime of my analytics for my website. It is showing a long "url", but without domain.
Can someone explain what it is and what do I need to do with it, or how to filter these kind of traffic:

```
/1/xhr42hmrvhycgcet5mu7zsp3.php?A8JF1316033699156c4712478e7c2aa7a41e45333c5c78026c4712478e7c2aa7a41e45333c5c78026c4712478e7c2aa7a41e45333c5c78026c4712478e7c2aa7a41e45333c5c78026c4712478e7c2aa7a41e45333c5c7802=&Official=&Pjdbbbdghsgsh=
```

Comment: Try to see in Analytics what domain that URL corresponds to.

Comment: It is a page view, in realtime I see a user at this page, but this page does not exists.

Comment: In Analytics you can find this page in page report, so check its domain

Comment: I checked, but there is no domain (where that user comes from), I only see the landing page url and the hostname (which is my domain). But the landing page url is a non existing url (therefor showing a 404 page), the above landing page is one of many I see as landing page urls. Seems that someone just added that to my domain in the address bar.

Comment: source / medium?

Comment: coming from direct

Comment: Check if you have checked 'exclude spam and bot' option in view settings

Comment: yes, it is checked already. but as the user is trying to go to a page that doesn't exists (with that insane long url added to the domain). My guess is someone is trying to "hack".

Comment: It can be even if I don't know what can be hacked with that URL (or what kind of error to generate if not a 404 ...). It should be analyzed if there is a recurrence with the hits that generate those page views, I don't know what to tell you more in this situation.